# Dreamhost making a domain fully hosted without creating a new FTP every time

Tags: dreamhost

I'm having trouble setting up a domain to be fully hosted under a specific FTP user.

When I go to Manage Domain -> Edit and under Fully Hosted, I only see the option to create a new user under User, Files and Paths. I want to set up the fully hosted domain on an already existing FTP user but I do not see that option. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps from my account:

1. Log into https://panel.dreamhost.com/
2. Click "Manage domains"
3. Click on the "Edit" button next to the domain
4. Use the "Run this domain under the user" option to set the FTP account

[image: dreamhost run this domain under the user]

Comment: Would you know why I am unable to see any users in the dropdown? Currently I see only Create a New User

Comment: Are there users in that drop down menu for your other domains?

Comment: I've check all of my other Fully Hosted domains. They have the user set but all of the drop downs only have Create a New User. I even tried creating a new user to see if it would appear in the dropdown.

Comment: Sounds like a bug at dreamhost then.   The dropdown has the appropriate users in it in my account.

Comment: @FarzadA are you the logging into the master user account where Dreamhost billing is setup or are you logging into the panel using a delegated user account?